# Visual Studio 2010- fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals; c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have been getting the error:

> asteroid.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static char (* Asteroid::Image)[4]" (?Image@Asteroid@@0PAY03DA)
>   1>C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\assignment3.1\Debug\assignment3.1.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

And I do not see what my problem is in Code. The only thing that changed in my program was making my "Image" and "LoadImage" member functions.

This is what my code in the header file looks like right now (skipping some public functions)

```
class Asteroid
{
private:
static const int ROWS = 3;
static const int COLUMNS = 4;
int row;
int column;
int row_size;
int column_size;
unsigned int ore_value;
static char Image[ROWS][COLUMNS];

public: static void LoadImage();
};
```

And this is what the LoadImage() Function looks like in the .cpp file

```
void Asteroid::LoadImage()
{
string myline;
ifstream asteroid_image_data("asteroid.txt");
if (asteroid_image_data.fail())
{
    cerr << "Asteroid image file is not available" << endl;
    return;
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    getline(asteroid_image_data, myline, '\n');
    if (!asteroid_image_data)
    {
        cerr << "Asteroid image file is missing some data" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
    {
        Image[i][j] = myline[j];
    }
}
asteroid_image_data.close();
}
```

The call from main.cpp is just

```
Asteroid::LoadImage();
```

Comment: what happen if you define image not static?

Comment: Your link doesn't show all your code

Comment: @MORTAL I get::: **1>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment3.1\assignment3.1\asteroid.cpp(38): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Asteroid::Image'
1>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment3.1\assignment3.1\asteroid.cpp(38): error C3867: 'Asteroid::Image': function call missing argument list; use '&Asteroid::Image' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment3.1\assignment3.1\asteroid.cpp(38): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type**

Comment: it's hard to know what cause it. and how to fix it without code. you probably need to write min-example if your code is long

Answer (score 1):

> You have to add a definition for the static char array
>
> Here is how to do it in the header cpp file:

```
   char Asteroid::Image[3][4] = { {'0','0','0','0'},
                                  { '0','0','0','0'},
                                  { '0','0','0','0'}
                                };
```

Or

```
   char Asteroid::Image[3][4];
```

> There is no problem like this, it works

```
Your header file (Header.h):

        #pragma once

        #include <string>

        using namespace std;

        class Asteroid
        {
        private:
            static const int ROWS = 3;
            static const int COLUMNS = 4;
            int row;
            int column;
            int row_size;
            int column_size;
            unsigned int ore_value;
            static char Image[ROWS][COLUMNS];

            public: static void LoadImage();
        };
```

**Header.cpp:**

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Asteroid::LoadImage()
{
    string myline;
    ifstream asteroid_image_data("asteroid.txt");

    if (asteroid_image_data.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Asteroid image file is not available" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        getline(asteroid_image_data, myline, '\n');

        if (!asteroid_image_data)
        {
            cerr << "Asteroid image file is missing some data" << endl;
            return;
        }

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            Image[i][j] = myline[j];
        }
    }
    asteroid_image_data.close();
}

char Asteroid::Image[3][4];
```

**main file (Source.cpp):**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Header.h""

    int main() {

        Asteroid::LoadImage();
    }
```

Comment: yes, i think OP doesn't declare the image. you can declare it like this `char Asteroid::Image[3][4]` without `{{0}}` compile will initialize it to zero since it is static.

Comment: It's ok i can change for that

Comment: Oh yes I understand now, thanks again, he have the choice I think